# Function that converts values to 0 or 1

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I'm looking for a function that takes a number between 0 and 1 and converts it into 0 if number is between 0 and 0.5, and into 1 if number is between 0.5 and 1.

So far I've got the first part, f(x) = max(x - 0.5, 0.0), but can't figure out how to continue the formula for the second part.

EDIT: The idea is to write it as one expression to avoid if branching.

Comment: Can  you tell me why $f(x) = 0$ if $0 \le x < .5$ $f(x) = 1$ if $.5 \le x \le 1$ is not acceptable?  That *is* a function and it's very well defined and calculable.

Comment: If the language you are using has a round function, then `round(x)` will do the trick. BTW, while it may make your code look cleaner (which may be the more important consideration), it'll almost surely be less CPU efficient to invoke a function rather than perform a branch. The only exception I can think of is if `round(x)` is an inline function.

Comment: Or probably `(int) (x >= 0.5)`.

Comment: @Χpẘ You're right regarding CPU, thing is in my case it's GPU and I use GLSL :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could just use a [piecewise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise) function, but if you're looking for a different option, this should work:
$$f(x) = \lfloor2x\rfloor$$
If $0<x<0.5$, then $0<2x<1$, so $\lfloor2x\rfloor=0$ and if $0.5<x<1$, then $1<2x<2$, so $\lfloor2x\rfloor=1$.

Comment: Damn I can't upvote now

Comment: Just wait another 25 minutes :P  But no, it's the thought that counts really!

Comment: I gotta admit, that was brilliant ^^

Comment: Don't want to be a spoilsport, but how is the floor function not a piecewise function, and why is the floor function any more or less acceptable then simply the function $f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } 0 \le x < 0.5\\1 &  \text{if } .5 \le x \le 1\end{cases}$

Comment: @fleablood I agree, the floor function is just a special type of piecewise function.  But, for some purposes it might be tidier to use the floor function, such as when programming (a call to floor is easier than an if statement).

Comment: I know.  But it is a *big* bugaboo pet-peeve of mine that beginning students often assume incorrectly to be a valid function it has to have some expressible formula and if the cant find it they can't express it as a function.  I *REALLY* want to abuse students of the notion.  If you can *say* "I want a function that returns 0 if x is less than .5 and returns 1 otherwise"  then that *IS* the function.  The student *HAS* found a function and described it *perfectly* adequately.

Comment: This indeed is brilliant, thanks :) The only issue here is that for 1 it will return 2, but it can easily be solved by adding min to it: min(floor(2*x), 1)

Comment: @user1617735 You might also like to check what happens at $x=0.5$, would you want a result of $0$ or $1$?

Comment: finally your +1 ^^

Comment: @fleablood +1 for the comment. Note: you want "disabuse", not "abuse".

Comment: Nah, I'm an abuser!

Comment: @B. Mehta In my case it's not that important :)

Comment: The usual programmer's trick for this kind of rounding is $f(x) = \left\lfloor x+\frac12\right\rfloor.$ This doesn't require any additional mechanism for the case $x=1.$ It also performs rounding within the intervals between other integers than just $0$ and $1,$ although for this application that's apparently not necessary.

Comment: @David K: Unfortunately that approach can get the wrong result when used with finite-precision binary floating-point arithmetic: If $x = 0.5 -  ulp$, the sum rounds to 1, while a result of 0 is desired. Example in C: `#include <stdio.h> #include <math.h> int main (void) { double half = 0.5; double x = nextafter (half, 0.0) /* 0.5-ulp */; printf ("%23.16e\n", floor (x + half)); return 0; }`

Comment: @njuffa That's an interesting point, because the result can depend on the rounding rules in force in your particular environment. If FP arithmetic rounds down, you get the desired result even when $x=0.5-ulp$; but a typical implementation rounds as you indicated. If you do $x+(0.5-ulp)$ instead of $x+0.5$ In such an environment, I believe the end result will be $0$ when $x=0.5-ulp$ and $1$ when $x=0.5.$ Maybe the lesson is to just use the `round` function from the math library.

Comment: @DavidK A rounding mode of "to-nearest-or-even" (RN) is the default on all common platforms, and doing additions with any other IEEE rounding mode is often difficult to set up. I agree that in C/C++, `round(x)` would work since the rounding mode for that is prescribed as "round to nearest, ties away from zero".

Answer (score 16):

"I'm looking for a function that takes a number between 0 and 1 and converts it into 0 if number is between 0 and 0.5, and into 1 if number is between 0.5 and 1."

And you've already found it.

A function is any relation (set of ordered pairs) where the first term is mapped to a unique second term.  That is all.  A function doesn't have to have a rule or formula to make it calculable.  ANything that can be unambiguously described is an acceptable function.

So the function you want is:

$f(x) =\begin{cases} 0 & \text {if } 0 \le x < .5 \\ 1 & \text {if } .5 \le x \le 1\end{cases}$.

That's it!  That is *all* you need to say.

Unless you are asking for a mathematical *formula*.

But in that case you should ask for a formula, not a function.  You already *have* the function.

It is "a function that takes a number between 0 and 1 and converts it into 0 if number is between 0 and 0.5, and into 1 if number is between 0.5 and 1".

Comment: Either that's a partial function, or the domain is not the reals...

Comment: The domain is [0,1].  The function isn't defined anywhere else.  The function ' s domain is implicit in its definition/description.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this is answer your question, but could it be the [Heaviside theta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) $\theta(x-0.5)$? You can write it as the derivative of the maximum function:
$$
\theta(x-0.5) = \frac{d}{dx}\max\{x-0.5,0\}=
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } x < 0.5\\
1 & \text{ if } x > 0.5
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 2):

$\def\sign{\operatorname{sign}}$

Using another piecewise function,
which is often included in a standard set of functions:

\begin{align} 
 \sign x &=
   \begin{cases} 
    -1 & \text{if } x < 0
  \\
  \phantom{-}0 & \text{if } x = 0
  \\
  \phantom{-}1 &  \text{if } x > 0
   \end{cases}
   \quad,
 \\
 f(x)&=\tfrac12(\sign(2x-1)+1)\cdot \sign(2x-1)
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Using the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket), one could describe the function simply as $[x>0.5],\; x\in [0,1]$.